# div/span and sprites

Tags: css, html

I am replacing most inline images on my sites with a sprite.

The sprite class would contain some basic css:

```
.sprite{
background-image:url(...);
background-position:...;
width: 16px;
height:16px;
}
```

I saw that nesting div inside of an anchor tag is not a good idea.

```
<a><div class="sprite"></div></a>
```

I've tried to add sprites to span elements instead.

```
<a><span class="sprite"></span></a>
```

But the span elements do not expand to the width and height that I set.
It would be really useful to be able to use span elements to replace image tags with a sprite.
I could add a blank gif image into the span element to expand it. But that would defeat the reason why I want to use sprites (to reduce the number of http requests).

Using div elements inside an anchor tag is not correct.

So how can I use sprites inside an anchor element?

And there also is always the problem of aligning the div. If an image is centered in another element, how do I replace it with a sprite?

Comment: Don't use sprites for content images. You sacrifice clear semantics, accessibility and maintainability. Reducing the number of HTTP requests isn't **that** important.

Comment: @David: Doesn't that depend on the number and size of the images?  I will agree though that it's a costly trade-off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare `display: block;` on your `span` elements which are by default inline elements. Something like:

```
.sprite{
    display: block;
    background-image:url(...);
    background-position:...;
    width: 16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

That should make the `span` elements expand to your desired width/height.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can we add a `width` or `height` to an inline element like `span` or are we simply converting it into `div` by using `display: block`?

Comment: You're pretty much just converting it to a `div`.

Comment: Yes, you can add width and/or height properties to the span, but they will be ignored unless you change its behavior, which is where `display: block;` comes into play, and no, the element is not being "converted" -- it's still a `span` -- but rather its default behavior is being changed and it will behave like a `div`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That solves the problem with not using div elements in an anchor tag. But it still brings a problem with centering the image in a parent element.

Comment: Since you have a fixed size for the element, you can always define the background's position in pixels relative to the element's top-left corner and center it "manually". However, there is no way of cropping a portion of a sprite through CSS in order to use it as a background in an element which is wider and/or taller, and the only solution (for non-repeating backgrounds only) is to leave enough empty space on the bottom-right side of that sprite so it would clear its element's right and bottom margin.

Comment: Anyways, if you want my honest opinion, unless you're doing rounded corners that *require* the use of images, using sprites for backgrounds simply isn't worth the hassle, not to mention that in some cases (a repeating background) it's impossible to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display property of the `span` element to `inline-block`

```
.sprite{
  background-image:url(...);
  background-position:...;
  width: 16px;
  height:16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This way the `span` element with the class of `.sprite` will accept `width` and `height` properties and will also act like `inline` elements.